# Reverse characters in Java while keeping some in place

Tags: java, string

I have a String and want to reverse it so that some characters get reversed, while others remain in place. How can I implement that (e.g. lets say I want all letters to reverse while all numbers stay in place)?

Comment: You can't reverse a character - you can reverse a string. Give a sample input/output.

Comment: @Erik, 'b' reversed would be 'd'.

Comment: @Erik, yes you are correct. I meant like below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an automaton for it:

iterate over the string, insert each letter into the stack and replace it with a special character which is not in the original string (i.e. $), do not change digits at all.

iterate over the string again, replace every $ with the head of the stack.

note: since String is immutable you will need to first export it to a StringBuilder or CharSequence

**EDIT**

for example:

```
    String inp = "a45string1test";
    char[] cs = new char[inp.length()];
    inp.getChars(0, inp.length(), cs, 0);
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i =0;i<cs.length;i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(cs[i])) continue;
        stack.push(cs[i]);
        cs[i] = '$';
    }
    for (int i=0;i<cs.length;i++) {
        if (cs[i] == '$') cs[i] = stack.pop();
    }
    System.out.println(cs);
```

result will be `t45setgni1rtsa`

complexity is O(n): iterating the string (twice) - since all stack operations are O(1).

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want something like myReverse("a1b2c3d") to be "d1c2b3a".

Use two indices, one going from each end of the string, looking for swappable characters.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
i1 = 0; i2 = len - 1;
while (i1 < i2) {
  while (isCharacterThatShouldNotBeSwapped(str.charAt(i1)) && i1 < i2)
    i1++;
  while (isCharacterThatShouldNotBeSwapped(str.charAt(i2)) && i1 < i2)
    i2--;
  if (i1 < i2)
    swapChars(str, i1, i2); /* swap characters at positions i1 and i2 in str */
  i1++; i2--;
}
```